# Mysterious Postgres string comparison result when string contains certain symbol characters

Tags: sql, postgresql, collation

My Postgres server gives me very confusing result while I try to compare strings which contains slash '/' or question mark '?'. For example in psql I ran:

```
select ('/' < '1') as c1,
       ('/1' < '1') as c2,
       ('/////1' < '1') as c3,
       ('/1' < '2') as c4,
       ('/1' < '11') as c5;
```

The result was:

```
 c1 | c2 | c3 | c4 | c5
----+----+----+----+----
 t  | f  | f  | t  | t
```

So `'/'` is smaller than `'1'`, but `'/1'` is larger than `'1'`. In fact `'/1'` is between `'1'` and `'2'` and so is `'/////1'`. This did not follow lexicographical order.

However, `'/1'` was (correctly) smaller than `11` which made me even more confused.

I wanted to see if `'/1'` is considered escaped. So I ran:

```sql
select length('/1');
```

and I got `2`, which meant that postgres does treat `'/1'` as a two character string.

The same problem happens when I replace `/` with other symbols such as `$` or `?`.

If you have docker, this problem is easily reproducible by runing a postgres in a docker container:

```
docker run postgres:11
docker exec  -it `docker ps | grep postgres:11 | cut -d' ' -f 1` psql -U postgres
```

Then try the above SQLs. I tried postgres 10 image and the behavior is the same.

The same thing happens to a real SQL when I compare a VARCHAR column with a string literal. This problem is driving me crazy since I need to write the correct SQL to compare file paths, which apparently contain many '/' symbols.

I searched and did not find any document talking about this so this doesn't look like a postgres 'official feature'. What is the right way to write a comparison that follows the lexicographical order?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postgres uses the operating system's collation (on Linux that would be the ones provided by `glibc`). So your results depend on the underlying operating system.

- Rextester seems to run on Windows, and there the comparison [works as expected](https://rextester.com/GBMJ84374)
- db<>fiddle works on Debian showing [the same behaviour](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=71a71f49b0175959baf8374d751a5043) as you see
- db-fiddle.com works on RedHat and there the comparison [works as expected](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8EbJgB29s1MPARDe2ETJLB/0) as well.

You can force an ASCCI comparison by using the `"C"` collation (as I did in the above examples):

```
select '/1' > '1' collate "C"
```

which seems to work the same on all platforms. Alternatively you can specify an [ICU](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/collation.html#COLLATION-MANAGING) collation that will also work the same across all platforms.

---

You mentioned you want to compare file paths. One way to do that only on the "names" (ignoring the delimiter") is to convert the path to an array `string_to_array(filepath, '/')` and then e.g. use that array for sorting or comparison.

Comment: Oh! You are a life-saver! Thank you!